# Showing an image in html from a URL within a JEditorPane. Possibly with ImageView?

Tags: java, swing, url, imageview, jeditorpane

I'm trying to download an image from the internet to show in a plugin. This plugin uses JEditorPane and contains html content. I have tried using a simple HTML code that would work in regular HTML:

```
imageUrl = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + smiles + "/image";
builder.append("<img src=" + imageUrl + "alt=\"molecule image\"/></p>");
```

Of course, I found that this would not work. All I'm getting is a broken square where the image should be. I have looked on the internet and found that the HTMLFactory ImageView might work, but I cannot find how to implement it.

If anyone could help, that would be great:)

note: builder is a stringbuilder in which I store the html content for the jeditorpane.

Comment: The `img` element is invalid.  AFAIR `JEditorPane` supports hot-linking to images just fine.  What is the value of `smiles`.. no scrap that, what is the the URL of the 'image', and where is a complete (short!) code example?

Answer (score 2):

http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html this could help